# How do you test Rails on Windows?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unit-testing

I was dismayed to find that rake takes 20+ seconds to load before running my Rails tests. I searched and it seems that everything in Rails is just much slower on Windows. I tried to use spork but it doesn't work on Windows.

So how do you test Rails on Windows? How do you setup your environment?

How about continuous testing?

Comment: Have you considered running a Virtual Machine with Ubuntu or something?

Comment: I was hoping to get an answer different than "Rails development is so painful in Windows that you're better off developing in another OS". I mean, is it really a farce that you can develop Rails applications on Windows? Is the whole RailsInstaller.org a big joke on people using Windows? (btw imo, painful-testing = no-testing = not-for-production-development) I'd like to hear from people who develop Rails on Windows, if they exist at all.

Comment: People do it, but you will run into gems that will not compile on Windows and you generally will have slower performance because some parts of the language/framework have not undergone a great deal of performance tuning on Windows. I guess I'd just be interested if you downloaded VirtualBox and Ubuntu (both free), how did the performance compare.

Comment: Yes I have and the performance is very good. I'm just trying to avoid going from a 10mb development environment (notepad++) to a 1gb one (an Ubuntu VM)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a TON of searches the takeaways are:

1) Ruby (and therefore Rails) on Windows is painfully slow.

2) There's an attempt to make Ruby faster on windows (https://github.com/thecodeshop/ruby/wiki/Downloads). Although it's not as fast as in *nix, it's fast enough to work with.

So the answer is: Avoid developing Rails on Windows if you can. If you still want/have to develop on Windows then replace your Ruby files with The Code Shop's Ruby build, it will give you a workable speed.

As a side note, for all the talk about being open, embracing diversity, etc. the Ruby and Rails community is very antagonistic to people asking how to do X or Y on Windows. On my searches most of the posts I saw were to the tone of "Winblows sux00rz! get a Mac or Linux".

**Update:**
I got spork + autotest + growl working on Windows so testing is much faster and automated. I put the instructions in this [blog post](http://www.manueldeleon.com/Blog/post/2012/07/30/Rails-Testing-on-Windows-%28The-Fast-and-Easy-Way%29.aspx).